# Resizing button size during run-time in C# with mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, windows-runtime

I am using following code to make and move buttons at runtime by mouse.

I want to also resize them with mouse. This code was provided by KekuSemau. Thanks a lot KekuSemau for this; it helped me.

```
private Point Origin_Cursor;
private Point Origin_Control;
private bool BtnDragging = false;



private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var b = new Button();
    b.Text = "My Button";
    b.Name = "button";
    //b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
    b.MouseUp += (s, e2) => { this.BtnDragging = false; };
    b.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseDown);
    b.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.b_MouseMove);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(b);
}

private void b_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button ct = sender as Button;
    ct.Capture = true;
    this.Origin_Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
    this.Origin_Control = ct.Location;
    this.BtnDragging = true;
}

private void b_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(this.BtnDragging)
    {
        Button ct = sender as Button;
        ct.Left = this.Origin_Control.X - (this.Origin_Cursor.X - Cursor.Position.X);
        ct.Top = this.Origin_Control.Y - (this.Origin_Cursor.Y - Cursor.Position.Y);
    }
}
```

I am having problem to change between the move and resize option . I want that when the mouse pointer is on the edges of the button , it should resize , when it is in center of the button it should move the button with mouse pointer .

Comment: thank you unheilig for editing.

Comment: A button control already has well-defined usage for the mouse, it generates the Click event.  No built-in support for resizing of course, that is something you do in the designer.  Which uses an overlay to intercept the mouse.  Very hard to guess why you want to do this at runtime, it just shouldn't be a button.  If you want to create your own designer then you should [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163871.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Controls (like button) in winforms usually have a size (width, height) and a location (x, y), where the units are pixels.

Modifying those properties is relatively straightforward: this shows an example where clicking on a button will make it 10 px wider and 10 px higher, and also move it 10 px to the right and 10 px down.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            button.Width = button.Width + 10;
            button.Height = button.Height + 10;

            button.Location = new Point(button.Location.X + 10, button.Location.Y + 10);

        }
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply and it works but i forgot to mention i wanted it to be with mouse , i want to resize them with mouse can u help me with that , i haved edited it in my post